# How to extract data based on timestamps in multiline log?

Tags: c#, parsing, timestamp

I have logs that have data in the format below. My question is this - Lets say I search the log for `12:22 PM`, how can I extract all information pertaining to that time-stamp only and output it... Is there a way I can say output everything from 12:22 PM onwards until you hit the next time-stamp? Thats essentially what I want to do programmatically. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you!

```
12:22 PM
    abc 
    def
       ghi
    abc
12:33 PM
    abc
    def
```

The output for the above mentioned case would be just this -

```
   12:22 PM
        abc 
        def
           ghi
        abc
```

Also please note: there could be multiple log entries with the same timestamp, for example, there could be 2 or 3 or maybe more entries under the same timestamp, i.e, `12:22 PM`

Comment: Use regex to validate the time stamp, something like `/^(0?[1-9]|1[012])(:[0-5]\d) [APap][mM]$/`, and if you don't have a time stamp match then it's an output line that you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a static function which will extract the required log from the given timestamp as below:

Note : I'm not handling exception scenario's[like FileNotFoundException and other exceptions], please handle them as per your requirement.

```
 static string GetLogsByTimeStamp(string timeStamp)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(timeStamp))
        {
            string filePath = @"F:\log.txt"; //your logfile path here
            string format = "hh:mm tt";
            TimeSpan reqTimeStamp = DateTime.ParseExact(timeStamp.Trim(),
                        format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).TimeOfDay;
            StringBuilder selectiveLogs = new StringBuilder(string.Empty);
            bool startReading = false;
            foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(filePath))
            {
                string[] arrItems = line.Split(new[] { ' ' }, 
                            StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                DateTime logDateTime = DateTime.MinValue;
                bool isDateTimeValid = false;
                if (arrItems != null && arrItems.Length > 1)
                    DateTime.TryParseExact(string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", 
                        arrItems[0].Trim(), " ", arrItems[1].Trim()), 
                                        format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                        DateTimeStyles.None, out logDateTime);
                TimeSpan logTimeStamp = logDateTime.TimeOfDay;
                if ((!startReading && logTimeStamp == reqTimeStamp) ||   
                                   (startReading && !isDateTimeValid))
                    startReading = true;
                if (startReading && logTimeStamp > reqTimeStamp)
                {
                    startReading = false;
                    break; // no need to continue when you know that u 
                           //reached greater timestamp than required.
                }
                if (startReading)
                    selectiveLogs.AppendLine(line);
            }
            return selectiveLogs.ToString();
        }
        else
            return string.Empty;
    }
```

You can use the above static function as below:

```
string requiredLog = GetLogsByTimeStamp("12:22 PM");
```